# Can an expert refuse to give expert testimony?

Tags: united-states, witnesses, testimony, subpoena

Can an expert be forced to give expert testimony with the use of a subpeona? Seeing as they are putting there reputation on the line it would not strike me as unfair to force a professional into forensic testimony?

Comment: It's not constitutional question, but US in general, fixed the tags. Just asked because the rules for experts are vastly different in other countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Yes and no, that is, the courts have extensive powers to compel testimony, but there are rules about doing so. [This article](https://www.expertinstitute.com/resources/insights/can-a-non-retained-expert-be-compelled-to-testify/) addresses the question of expert testimony. Suppose you want an expert to testify, then Rule [26(a)(2)(B)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_26#rule_26_a_2_B) applies, requiring disclosure of the information to be disclosed, along with a written report. It could be nearly impossible to provide the required information without the cooperation of the expert. Furthermore, under [Rule 45(d)(3)(B)(ii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_45), a subpoena can be quashed, which the article summarizes in terms of the objections that

> Testimony about an expert’s findings may impact or limit an expert’s ability to conduct research
>
> Testimony about an expert’s work may be unethical, if the work is not
> completed, peer reviewed, or otherwise in a “publishable” format
>
> The subpoena and resultant testimony could put the expert at a
> competitive disadvantage
>
> Work required to adequately prepare for such testimony is overly
> burdensome
>
> The subpoena and subsequent testimony may put the unwilling expert in
> a controversial or otherwise uncomfortable position

In a specific instance of subpoenaing an involuntary witness, the court in [In Re: World Trade Center Lower Manhattan Disaster Site Litigation](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20150116a08) addressed a motion to compel expert testimony. The opinion lays out various powers of the court to compel a "non-retained" expert witness, including the "substantial need for the testimony or material that cannot be otherwise met without undue hardship". There is a complex weighing of factors here, which is resolved at the finding that "Plaintiffs have failed to show that the Non-Retained Experts' testimony is unique" so the petition to compel testimony was denied, *but* the affiliated research center was compelled to disclose the underlying data.

So it depends on the circumstances, see [Kaufman v. Edelstein](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19761350539f2d81111216), 539 F.2d 811.